# Mysql counting all the colums which contain the number 1, 2, 3 or 4

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which contains eleven (11) columns all of which will hold either the number 1,2,3 or 4. I need to create a query that will count all the rows where each column contains either 1, 2, 3, or 4.

So, if:

```
row 1, col A = 2
row 1, col B = 3
row 1, col C = 1
row 1, col D = 4
row 1, col E = 4
```

and

```
row 2, col A = 1
row 2, col B = 4
row 2, col C = 4
row 2, col D = 4
row 2, col E = 4
```

How can I produce the result that returns:

```
col A contains the number "2" once returns 1
col A contains the number "1" once returns 1
col B contains the number "3" once returns 1
col B contains the number "4" once returns 1
col C contains the number "1" once returns 1
col C contains the number "4" once returns 1
col D contains the number "4" twice returns 2
col D contains the number "4" twice returns 2
```

Would i have to create a query for each column like below, or can this be done using only one query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FeedBackDate, '%M') AS 'Month', COUNT(RecordID) AS 'Total'  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE HotelID = '". $_SESSION['hotelid'] ."' 
AND ColA = 1 

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FeedBackDate, '%M') AS 'Month', COUNT(RecordID) AS 'Total'  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE HotelID = '". $_SESSION['hotelid'] ."' 
AND ColA = 2 

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FeedBackDate, '%M') AS 'Month', COUNT(RecordID) AS 'Total'  
FROM ".$FeedBack." 
WHERE HotelID = '". $_SESSION['hotelid'] ."' 
AND ColA = 3
```

and so on. I hope I have explained this enough so it is understood.

Many thanks in advance foir your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how often a value per column occurs. With the given datamodel, you'd have to get one result list per column und then glue these result lists together with `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'COL A' as col, col_a as value, count(*) as occurrences
from mytable
group by col_a
union all
select 'COL B' as col, col_b as value, count(*) as occurrences
from mytable
group by col_b
union all
select 'COL C' as col, col_c as value, count(*) as occurrences
from mytable
group by col_c
...
order by col, value;
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply, nearly there. I can echo out the "occurrences" but how can I echo out the column names. At the moment I don't know which of the results relate to which coloumn.

Comment: Er, have you actually looked at the results? The rows where column `col` has the text `'COL A'` refer to `col_a` naturally; those with `'COL B'` refer to `col_b` and so on.

Comment: Sorry, my stupid fault for not looking past the end of my nose. Many thanks for your time. This is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 5.5 you can use Stored Routines :

[20.2 Using Stored Routines (Procedures and Functions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines.html)